# Ошибка в парсинге сайта

Tags: python, парсер, telebot, bs4

```
@bot.command()
async def testpy(ctx):
    r = requests.get('https://www.blitzstars.com/player/ru/sayuu', headers = HEADERS)
    a = BS(r.content, "lxml")
    w = a.find_all("tr", class_="tanks-table-row ng-scope")
    print(w)
```

Бот выводит [], не понимаю почему. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что метод find_all bs4 ищет все теги tr которых в ответе сервера нет